# Objective C - How to receive two int in same parameter

Tags: objective-c

I need to write a method like this:

```
-(void)doStuff:(int)options;
```

Based in the a typedef enum like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    FirstOption,
    SecondOption,
    ThirdOption
} MyOptions
```

What I need to to do in order to be able to call the method in this way (i.e. calling the method with more than one option "enabled":

```
[self doStuff:(FirstOption | ThirdOption)];
```

Do I need to setup the `typedef enum` differently? And how I check the options received in the method, a simple `if (options == ...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call for is a bit array. Define your options like this:

```
enum MyOptions
{
    FirstOption = 0x01, // first bit
    SecondOption = 0x02, // second bit
    ThirdOption = 0x04, // third bit
    ... = 0x08 ...
};
```

Combine the options like you suggested, with `|`, and test for them with `&` (`options & SecondOption`).

```
- (void) doStuff: (MyOptions) options
{
    if ( options & FirstOption )
    {
        // do something fancy
    }

    if ( options & SecondOption )
    {
        // do something awesome
    }

    if ( (options & SecondOption) && ( options & ThirdOption) )
    {
        // do something sublime
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity I would add something explicit about the numbers being powers of two.

Comment: You could also use the built-in binary notation available if it makes it easier to read for you: `0b0001`, `0b0010`, `0b0100`, `0b1000`.

Comment: The conventions in apples code is to do a bitshift operation when setting up these masks: `FirstOption = 1, SecondOption = 1 << 1;`

Comment: @fabricetruillotdechambrier I am not being able to test for them with `&`. If you could please explain more, or explain about Apple conventions would be perfect.

Comment: It's not Apple-ish things, it's basic C. But hop, added an example.

Comment: @fabricetruillotdechambrier Merci ;)

Comment: A votre service, Monsieur. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert at Obj-C, but in other languages I would use flags. If each value is a power of two, then it will have only one bit set for that value. You can use that bit as a bool for a particular option.

```
FirstOption = 1
SecondOption = 2
ThirdOption = 4

FirstAndThird = FirstOption | ThirdOption; // Binary Or sets the bits

// Binary And checks the bits
IsFirst = FirstAndThird & FirstOption == FirstOption; // is true
IsSecond = FirstAndThird & SecondOption == SecondOption; // is false
IsThird = FirstAndThird & ThirdOption == ThirdOption; // is true
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524362/how-to-use-enums-with-bit-flags) may also be of use.

Comment: Compile errors/warnings with `IsFirst = FirstAndThird & FirstOption == FirstOption`

Comment: It's a language agnostic example.