# Magic of casting value to bool

Tags: c++, windows

Today I realized that casting a value to a bool is a kind of magic:

```
int value = 0x100;
unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>(value);
bool b = static_cast<bool>(value);
```

Both `sizeof(uc)` and `sizeof(b)` return `1`. I know that `uc` will contain 0x00, because only the LSB is copied. But `b` will be `true`, so my assumption is that, when casting to `bool`, the value gets evaluated instead of copied.

Is this assumption correct? And is this a standard C++ behavior?

Comment: It's one of the dark arts.

Comment: Everything not `0` is true, and since `0x100` is not `0`  ...

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe of some other SO question, but anyway, from C++03: "An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool.  A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true."

Comment: @MichaelBurr couldn't find that 'dupe' on SO either. Even Dr. Google didn't help me here.

Comment: Also note that strictly speaking the conversion from  `int` to `unsigned char` is also "evaluated". The evaluation results in the lsb being copied only on two's complement machines (admittedly that's pretty much every machine out there today). For example, on a 32-bit one's complement machine, -1 would be represented as `0xfffffffe`, but the conversion `unsigned char uc = (unsigned char)(-1);` would result in `uc == 0xff`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing magical about it. The conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` is defined as `value % 256` (for 8-bit `char`s), so that is what you get. It can be implemented as copying the LSB, but you should still think about it in the semantic sense, not the implementation.

On the same vein, conversion of `int` to `bool` is defined as `value != 0`, so again, that is what you get.

Integral (and boolean) conversions are covered by the C++11 standard in `[conv.integral]` and `[conv.bool]`. For the C-style cast, see `[expr.cast]` and `[expr.static.cast]`.

Comment: So you say this is standard C++ behavior and is safe to use? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I've added references to the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, when casting to `bool`, the value gets evaluated, not copying.

In fact, in your example, as long as `value` is not `0`, `b` will be `true`.

Update: Quoting from **C++ Primer** 5th Edition Chapter 2.1.2:

`When we assign one of the nonbool arithmetic types to a bool object, the
result is false if the value is 0 and true otherwise.`

Answer (score 4):

It is a part of the standard:

> **4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]**
>
> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
>   to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to false; any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [rules for C-style casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), `(bool)value` is effectively a `static_cast`. The first rule for `static_cast` then kicks in, which computes the value of a temporary "declared and initialized ... as by `new_type Temp(expression);`", i.e. `bool Temp(value);`. That's well-defined: `Temp` is `true` iff `value != 0`. So yes, `value` is "evaluated" in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `bool` is a feature inherited from plain old C. Originally, C didn't have a `bool` type, and it was useful to use other types in `if` statements, like so:

```
int myBool = 1;
if(myBool) {
    // C didn't have bools, so we had to use ints!
}

void* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(!p) {
    // malloc failed to allocate memory!
}
```

When you're converting to `bool`, it acts just like you're putting the statement in an `if`.

Of course, C++ is backwards compatible with C, so it adopted the feature. C++ also added the ability to overload the conversion to `bool` on your classes. `iostream` does this to indicate when the stream is in an invalid state:

```
if(!cout) {
    // Something went horribly wrong with the standard output stream!
}
```

Comment: I've worked with C compilers (MPLAB if I remember correct) that define a bool like: `typedef char bool;`, so `bool b = (bool)0x100` on that compiler would definitely result in `b` being `false`.

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC C++ Standard:

> 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool] 1 A prvalue of arithmetic... type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value... is converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

So, since a *prvalue* is a value, you might say that the value gets evaluated, albeit that's kind of pleonastic.