# Understand about bitwise operator and comparing them

Tags: objective-c, enums, comparison, bitwise-operators

**Summary** (For tho who want the tl;dr version, you may skip to the question below):

I've just gone through this problem: [Comparing UIDeviceOrienation and UIInterfaceOrientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015709/xcode-getting-warning-implicit-conversion-from-enumeration-type-uideviceorient). After that, I took a look at how bitwise work (because I've seen them sometimes, but not really understand how they work.)

So, I've taken a research about [What's bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/understanding-the-bitwise-and-operator), [How enum in objective-c work with bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176149/multiple-value-enum-in-obj-c), [How to use enum that's in bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524362/how-to-use-enums-with-bit-flags).

**(TL;DR)** Now, here's my question:

Let's say, I want to check if my UIInterfaceOrientation = Landscape (Left | Right) should I use it like this:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ==
     (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft |
      UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```

OR

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation & 
    (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | 
     UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```

Should they give the same result? Or different? Which one is more appropriate?

(In my simple mind, if it's not wrong then the second one is more appropriate).

**BONUS QUESTION**

Other than enums, is there anywhere else where I can use bitwise, bitshift operator effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do:

The **first** approach means:

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft AND UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight is set and no other options (even with different semantics) are set.

This will never be true, because UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight are mutually exclusive.

The **second** approach means:

UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft OR UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight is set and other options are ignored.

Likely this is what you want to do.

But you should really read something about bit operations. There are a mass of tutorials in the web. You can use every tutorial dealing with C, too.

Bonus Q:

a. What is the bonus I get?

b. Yes, you do not need an `enum` to declare constants. You can simply do that with global constants:

```
const int Option1 = 1 << 0;
const int Option2 = 1 << 1;
…
```

c. Beside this you can do some arithmetic magic with bit operations, like dividing and multiplying with powers of 2, checking, whether a number is even or odd, …

Comment: Bonus Q.a: You get one upvote from me :)) Thanks for the answer.